# How to comment an element and how to add a new element to a specific place on XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm learning xml with c# and I'm trying to find a element on xml(inside other element) and comment this element, after that, I want to add a element in that place, but I don't know how to do this and the way more simple.

Someone can help?

Comment: Try *Linq to Xml*, `System.Xml.Linq` namespace. Query xml, find all the elements required and modify them in `foreach` loop

Comment: @DmitryBychenko okay I will search about it thx

Comment: you can  search the specific ```XElement```  node,use ```AddBeforeSelf(XElement e)``` or  ```AddAfterSelf(XElement e)``` method  add a new element to the specific place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview). It's very convenient and powerful.

```
var xe = XElement.Load(@"c:\example.xml");
var xbook = xe.DescendantsAndSelf().First(i=>i.Name=="Book");
xbook.AddBeforeSelf(new XComment("Some Comment"));
xe.Save(@"C:\new.xml");
```